# mysql error upload dump 'applications_question'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to upload a dump, everything is excellent apart from this fragment:

```
CREATE TABLE `applications_question` (
  `application_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  KEY `application_id` (`application_id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_application_id` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#1005 - `ru_web`.`applications_question` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Having demolished it, all the elements are loaded calmly, but the site does not want to work without it

So that the entire dump can be safely loaded without errors

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `applications`;

CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('WAITING','ACCEPT','DECLINE','ARCHIVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'WAITING',
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `sex` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `race` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `skin` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `age` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `role` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spawn` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `document` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `history` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `admin_ip` varchar(17) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `admin_comment` varchar(512) DEFAULT '',
  `admin_view_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `admin_view_update` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `applications` */

insert  into `applications`(`id`,`user_id`,`status`,`name`,`sex`,`race`,`skin`,`age`,`role`,`spawn`,`document`,`item`,`history`,`ip`,`admin_id`,`admin_ip`,`admin_comment`,`admin_view_id`,`admin_view_update`,`create_date`,`update_date`) values 
(22,1,'ACCEPT','Testm_Testm',0,1,255,0,0,0,0,-1,'tewttw','127.0.0.1',1,'127.0.0.1','i9',0,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','2019-12-16 01:18:19','2019-12-16 01:18:19'),
(23,1,'ACCEPT','Testtt_Testewew7',0,1,255,14,0,0,1,-1,'test','127.0.0.1',1,'127.0.0.1','',0,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','2019-12-16 01:19:29','2019-12-16 01:19:29');
```

And code with question_id

```
/*Table structure for table `questions` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `questions`;

CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `questions` */

insert  into `questions`(`id`,`text`,`create_date`,`update_date`) values 
(1,'testtest','0000-00-00 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
(2,'testtest','0000-00-00 00:00:00','2019-07-02 04:55:44'),
(3,'wetwetwet','2019-07-02 04:52:32','1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
(5,'cxbxb','2019-07-02 04:55:51','1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
(6,'testtest','2019-12-17 22:31:23','2019-12-17 22:31:27'),
(7,'testtest','2019-12-17 22:31:35','2019-12-17 22:31:35');
```

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables referenced in the FK.